# What is the best way to convert console app to Azure trigger

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-functions

I have a console application that runs and monitors an Azure service bus queue. The function I have accepts a Message class and processes it. The app registers the function.

Now I need to convert it to run when a message comes into the message bus queue.

All of the examples I see show a static class with a static method with some parameters being decorated by attributes. It shows the message being sent as being a string.

But my method has a Message class being sent to it.

If I want to use that same app as the azure function app, what should I do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Reuse the *logic* of the old app.

You can't, of course, use the console app *itself* as your Azure Functions app ... Azure Functions is its own runtime & execution framework. That said, you can probably reuse most of the *logic* from your console app with surprisingly few tweaks.

Since you say you are using the [Message](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.servicebus.message?view=azure-dotnet) class, I assume you are using the .NET Core ServiceBus libraries. If so, you should use the Azure Functions v2 runtime. If you are using the older, full framework ServiceBus library with the *[BrokeredMessage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.servicebus.messaging.brokeredmessage?view=azure-dotnet)* class, you'll want to stick to the Functions v1 runtime.

The "bindings" in Azure Functions are pretty flexible and often know how to supply what you need. You are probably seeing examples like this:

```
[FunctionName("NewSbMessageArrivedFunction")]                    
public static void Run(
    [ServiceBusTrigger("someQueue")] string queueMessage, TraceWriter log)
{
    ...
}
```

You can actually just change the *queueMessage* argument in this example from a `string` to a `Message` (or a `BrokeredMessage` in v1), and the runtime will see the different signature and should populate your message object for you!

For more details on how this works and what other properties you can bind to for the ServiceBus trigger, check out the documentation on [Azure Functions ServiceBus Bindings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-service-bus#trigger---usage).

Comment: Hello, just a quick question if I may: When you say reuse most of the logic do you mean; that I am forced to create a new project which is an azure function? Or is there a way to modify the console app I have ( e.g: change the triggers, etc...).

Comment: Correct, you cannot deploy a console executable to Azure Functions. If you want to prepare for the transition while maintaining the ability to compile and use your console app, then you should move your logic to a class library which both your console app and a new function app can reference.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend the accepted answer of re-using the logic and creating a new Azure function project. However, as an alternative, you can use Azure functions to call an executable running in a VM.

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-au/resources/samples/functions-dotnet-migrating-console-apps/